# Can "form" and "layout" be used together in rendering an input-view?

Tags: bixby

I want to layout some text above an input form but I am having trouble figuring out how to get Bixby to accept them both as children of render. Is that even possible?  the error message complains about the content of render being both empty and multi-cardinal (?).[image]

```
      render {

        layout { section { content { paragraph { value ("Each AltBrain tracks a particular topic and prepares news, facts, images, and social media for you to review.  What would you like this AltBrain to track?")}}

         }
        }

        form {
          elements {
            text-input {
              id (comments)
              type (Comments)
              label (Example: The Witcher on Netflix.)
              max-length (72)
              value ("#{raw(comments)}")
            }
          }
          on-submit {
            goal: Comments
            value: viv.core.FormElement(comments)

          }
          submit-button (Next)
        }
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Input-view only allows one input component. So layout and form will only render the first one (which is the warning message on form). Now for the layout error message, it is wired and I will update you later once I found out more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy answer: `form` cannot be used together with `layout`, the later one will be unreachable.

The more difficult question, when do I use `layout` in input-view?

Check the following code as example. It is used to provide an extra selection/confirm step when only 1 valid value for a required input in an action.

```
  render {
if (size(this)==1) {
  layout {
    section {
      content {
        title-area {
          slot1 {
            text ("You sure are #{value(this)} years old?")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    select-button-text ("confirm")
  }
}
else-if (size(this)>1) {
  selection-of (this) {
    where-each (item) {
      title-card {
        title-area {
          slot1 {
            text ("Select #{value(item)}")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
else {
  form {
    elements {
      number-input {
        id (that)
        label (Age)
        type (IntAge) 
      }
    }
    on-submit {
      goal: IntAge
      value: viv.core.FormElement(that)
    }
  }
}
```

}

In case of only 1 value, the view is like this (the `select-button-text` is required here). Make sure the in action model, this input has `prompt-behavior (AlwaysSelection)`
[image]